# Transferring a value to another class, changing it and returning it back to the main class

Tags: c#, winforms

There are 2 classes `Beauty_VScrollBar.cs` and `RTB.cs`.
From the *first* class the name of the element, converted to `RichTextBox`, is passed. The *second* class binds event handlers to the received name, performs calculations and writes the value to the variable `Maximum`. The resulting value is passed back to the *first* class.

Problem: **The value is calculated only once. When you try to change the dimensions of a component (internal or external), the calculation is not done again.**

**Beauty_VScrollBar.cs**

```
private Control bindingContainer;
public Control BindingContainer {
    get { return bindingContainer; }
    set {
        bindingContainer = value;
        Updates(); Invalidate();
    }
}

private void Updates() {
    if (bindingContainer is RichTextBox) {
        RTB.Name = (RichTextBox)bindingContainer;
        RTB.BindEventHandlers(); Maximum = RTB.Maximum;
    } else if (bindingContainer is Panel) {
        PNL.Name = (Panel)bindingContainer;
        PNL.BindEventHandlers(); Maximum = PNL.Maximum;
    } else {
        bindingContainer = null;
        MessageBox.Show("The selected item is not a RichTextBox");
    }
}
```

**RTB.cs**

```
public static class RTB {
    public static RichTextBox Name { get; set; }
    public static int Maximum { get; private set; }

    private static int heightContentRtb;
    private static int heightContainerRtb;

    public static void BindEventHandlers() {
        Name.Resize += (s, e) => SetMaxVScroll();

        Name.ContentsResized += (s, e) => {
            heightContentRtb = e.NewRectangle.Height; SetMaxVScroll();
        };
    }

    private static void SetMaxVScroll() {
        heightContainerRtb = Name.ClientSize.Height;
        Maximum = Math.Abs(heightContentRtb - heightContainerRtb + 1);
    }
}
```

**If you do everything in one class - everything works, but it is not convenient to update.**

*Note: In addition to RichTextBox, other types will be used, so we need transformations (... as RichTextBox).*

```
private RichTextBox targetCtrl;
public RichTextBox TargetCtrl {
    get { return targetCtrl; }
    set {
        targetCtrl = value;
        Updates(); Invalidate();
    }
}

private void Updates() {
    if (targetCtrl != null) targetCtrl.Resize += TargetCtrl_Resize;
    if (targetCtrl != null) targetCtrl.ContentsResized += TargetCtrl_ContentsResized;
}

int heightContentRtb;

private void TargetCtrl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SetMaxVScroll();
}

private void TargetCtrl_ContentsResized(object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e) {
    heightContentRtb = e.NewRectangle.Height; SetMaxVScroll();
}

private void SetMaxVScroll() {
    int heightContainerRtb = targetCtrl.ClientSize.Height;
    Maximum = Math.Abs(heightContentRtb - heightContainerRtb + 1);
}
```

Comment: Be careful, you set the same Control more than once to `BindingContainer` you will have duplicated events on you ritchtextbox. When is the one time that the calculation is done?

Comment: You cannot **convert** the **name** (string) of an element to a `RichTextBox`; however, you can **cast** a variable (in fact an expression) of type `Control` to the type `RichTextBox` if it contains one.

Comment: You are assigning an eventhandler that contains a static method as a lambda expression that uses a static field (`Name`) which is the target that gets the eventhandler. Could be that the context of the event is getting messed up when you use it for more than one Control?

Comment: Calculations occur when a RichTextBox is filled with items, scaled, or resized.

Comment: I tried creating an instance of the class "Beauty_VScrollBar vScrollBar = new Beauty_VScrollBar()" and referring to the variable as follows: vScrollBar.Maximum. The same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reusing `RTB` for multiple controls then you are clobbering (overwriting) the value of `Name` each time. The event handler still gets registered to each but when the event handler runs it is in the context of whatever the current value of `Name` is because `Name` is `static`.

If you dont like the 2nd version that you've listed and want you code closer together you could create a closure to handle the event assignment and `Maximum` calculation. A closure would maintain separate state each time it is called. However your 2nd version seems alright to me.

```
pubilc void setup(RichTextBox name){
     int heightContentRtb = 0;
     int heightContainerRtb = 0;

     void SetMaxVScroll() {
        heightContainerRtb = Name.ClientSize.Height;
        Maximum = Math.Abs(heightContentRtb - heightContainerRtb + 1);
    }

    name.Resize += (s, e) => SetMaxVScroll();
    Name.ContentsResized += (s, e) => {
        heightContentRtb = e.NewRectangle.Height;
        SetMaxVScroll();
    };
}
```

Note:
It is not clear to me what the purpose of `Maximum` is or where it should live. And in the above code it would get overwritten each time a particular RichTextBox control is resized.

Comment: I'm writing a `custom scrollbar` and so I took create the `BindingContainer` property. When I put the scrollbar on a form and want to connect it to some scrollable element (`Panel, FlowLayoutPanel, TableLayoutPanel, RichTextBox`), I refer to the `BindingContainer` property (it offers a list of names of elements on the form). After that, I bring the variable to the appropriate type and bind event handlers that calculate the `Max`. If I don't recalculate it, I won't be able to scroll any further than the originally set value (`Max` = 100) when adding or resizing items.

Comment: golakwer, your solution worked for me, using it I can simply pass a parameter with the type I want and immediately edit the event handlers. Note: Addressing via an additional class was unsuccessful.